# What is the 't' folder?

Tags: directory-structure, source, opensource-projects

I'm mainly a Windows guy, programming C#, but I often do use technologies that were intended for Linux machines like git, MySQL, perl scripts, memcached, php, etc... And therefore I am exposed to these tools.

I like looking at the code base of these tools every once in a while, and something I realized in many code bases is a folder called `t` with a bunch of files with the `t` extension.

What are these files?

How come the folder doesn't have a more descriptive name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are these files?

The `$PROJECT/t` directory is the canonical place for a project to keep its automated unit tests.

> How come the folder doesn't have a more descriptive name?

By adhering to what is basically a standard naming convention, it is perfectly descriptive of what files go into this directory.

Other programmers will expect to find a `/t` subdirectory containing unit tests. It would be confusing if they decided to call it something different.

I am not sure why this is a standard, but presumably it is because `/t` would not likely be used as a name for some other component of a project (whereas `/test` could feasibly refer to something different than unit tests in the context of a given project).

It is also faster to type `./t/check_something`.

Comment: Thanks. I think the problem is that we [programmers] got used to bad IDE's for too long. With nowadays' IDE's and technologies like Intellisense (Microsoft's term - don't know what it's called in other IDE's) there's no need for being cheap with naming. Not in code and not in the structure tree... :)

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, the `t/` directory usually include automated tests.

Quoting from the [Git  `t/README` file](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/t/README)

> ## Core GIT Tests
>
> This directory holds many test scripts for core GIT tools.